# Can't access docker containers from outside the host os

Tags: docker, ubuntu, unix

I'm running docker containers on a server with Ubuntu 20.04. When I reboot the server, the container can be accessed from outside, but after like 24 hours, it becomes inaccessible from outside, but still accessible from the host.
The docker command is `docker run --name nginx_test -p 8001:80 -d nginx` which basically runs a nginx server in it. When execute `curl 192.168.1.2:8001` inside the host os (whose ip is 192.168.1.2), it returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

showing the nginx server is running. But from another computer in the same network, it will result in timeout,getting nothing.
executing `docker network inspect bridge` returns:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "699360ceb173ee8e6e1009638b3cc96e0bf6dbcde9a8bf7f6cf5b93ce11b4621",
        "Created": "2023-08-21T22:40:18.067084419+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "17553b703b32a973133d5b50df56f216833c9899ab68afefcf45ea09ea3be60f": {
                "Name": "nginx_test",
                "EndpointID": "f0c8bc6e8afe8fde20409fd0e3088fa7432095e0177c7805fd33b98bb50e67fd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c902a10cd55e56d61c3ce4bb942f6278450b552200e9c4a72eb058642bfefc47": {
                "Name": "aria2-pro",
                "EndpointID": "e4d3e24b9a6088bbb7eb2158b9fba8fc282ee11401a22d2499c73f7f81a6ea7b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "eaeb641c07e61f55222d0ac000495e2c8357d030846a62a4dc3136298758e50b": {
                "Name": "ariang",
                "EndpointID": "d5f229d496f2d70ddd11f8601ba614ea9e808aefd776d28c93c4dbb208f29a82",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Executing `iptables -L` returns

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ts-input   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ts-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:6888
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           udp dpt:6888
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:6800
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:6880

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68

Chain ts-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK xset 0x40000/0xff0000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x40000/0xff0000
DROP       all  --  100.64.0.0/10        anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ts-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  100.97.43.80         anywhere
RETURN     all  --  100.115.92.0/23      anywhere
DROP       all  --  100.64.0.0/10        anywhere
```

Tried rebooting the machine, the container becomes accessible, but becomes inaccessible after 24 hours or so.
Tried delete and recreate the container, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use host driver to map your container ip , alsoe check ufw and allow http port

Comment: If I use `--network host` the containers works fine, but I don't want it to be that way since I have tproxy configured to relay non-docker traffic to another server, and I don't want docker containers to be proxied